# Installing package

Tags: r, bioconductor

I come across this problem when I install the package

"TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene" from Bioclite on RStudio v.1.1442. Below is the error message: 
Warning messages:
/TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene_3.2.2.tar.gz' had status 3 
2: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene’ had non-zero exit status

I also tried to install this package, but it did not work either: 
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘parallel’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘parallel’ is a base package, and should not be updated

I do not understand what the warnings mean and can someone please help me with resolving this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use the "Tools>Install_packages" route, or the "biocLite(...)" route?

Comment: Probably answered here: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/64228/

Comment: @RussHyde: I installed via the biocLite route.

Comment: @anyanwu: I tried but it did not work on my RStudio version. Thank you.

Comment: Could you confirm that you have installed the dependencies: AnnotationDbi / GenomicFeatures

Comment: @RussHyde I installed the AnnotationDbi/GenomicFeatures but an error was reported that the packages are not available for the current R version that I am using (R v.3.4.3)

Comment: They're both bioconductor packages; please retry with biocLite().

Comment: @RussHyde: I installed via biocLite(), but the same error kept appearing. I also tried to remove the downloaded zip TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene_3.2.2.tar.gz package (yet it is blank), but I was not still able to install the package via biocLite again. Do you have any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 0):

Some further details would be *very* helpful - especially the code that you actually used.
What OS are you working on?
Is this a fresh install of R?
Have you previously had TxDB.... installed?
Are you working in a conda environment or similar?
Why did you download the gzipped version of the package?

In a fresh R-3.4.3 environment on Ubuntu I get the following

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

## installing source BiocInstaller blah blah success

biocLite("TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene")

Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘GenomicFeatures’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene’ had non-zero exit status
```

This suggests that if I wanted to install TxDB... I'd have to get RMySQL installed first, and then GenomicFeatures and then ....

Could you post all the code you used and all the contents of the warning messages that you received, please.

Comment: Here are the codes that I used: source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("BiocParallel")
biocLite("parallel")
biocLite("ShortRead")
biocLite("RSQLite")
biocLite("QuasR")
biocLite("BSgenome")
biocLite("Rsamtools")
biocLite("rtracklayer")
biocLite("GenomicFeatures")
biocLite("Hmisc")
biocLite("Gviz")
biocLite("XML")
biocLite("mosaics")
biocLite("ChIPseeker")
biocLite("TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene")

Comment: I am working on a  Windows 10 computer. Previously, I tried to install TxDB but as I got the same error and warning message, I tried to solve the problem by deleting the TxDB in the temp folder. My RStudio version also indicates that yaml package is old, so I also had to reinstall the yaml package.

Comment: Please trim your code down to the smallest bit that throws the error. 
    You shouldn't be using biocLite to install CRAN packages (parallel, RSQLite, XML, Hmisc; use install.packages() for these and then use biocLite() for each of the others in turn) and you've no reason to install parallel (since it's installed with base R; see your second warning in your initial post).   So: install the CRAN packages in turn, then install the bioconductor packages in turn and when the first package fails post the precise error message back here.